How to output the correlation/euclidian value for the dendogram in pheatmap R?
Using pheatmap in R, I would like to know if there is a way to output the euclidian distance/correlation value used in clustering? I understand that these are represented by the dendogram branches but I am unsure on how to add a legend for euclidian distances or to print out the correlation value for the branch.
library(pheatmap)

pheatmap(
data, 
clustering_distance_cols = "correlation",
main = "Proteome vs Transcriptome",
legend = TRUE,
clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean",
scale = "none"
)


Above is the general code I use. Specifically, I want to extract and print the value in clustering_distance_cols = "correlation". If possible as well, I'd like to add a legend for clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean". Looking through the arguments for this, there doesn't seem to be a direct way to print out the value.
I am also open to learning other packages that may have this function.
Thank you so  much for any advice you may offer for this!

You can store the result of pheatmap like:
my_heatmap <- pheatmap(...)


To show the heatmap, print (not plot) the result:

print(my_heatmap)


To display values in the heatmap's cells, include:

my_heatmap <- pheatmap(..., display_numbers = TRUE)


to separately inspect the clustering results of rows, columns, extract them like:

my_heatmap$tree_col

... and handle those like any hclust object (see ?hclust), e. g.
... plot a dendrogram
plot(my_heatmap$tree_col)

... or extract cluster parameters:
my_heatmap$tree_col$height
## [1] 0.4185528 0.8017643 1.4606777 1.6327649

